# Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Two of my tables are failing to join.  Running

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  `A`.`id` 
FROM  `demo`.`A` AS  `A` 
INNER JOIN  `demo`.`B` AS  `B` 
ON (  `A`.`id` = 'B.A_id' )
```

yields

```
extra="Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables"
```

in the result.  All my research show that this message should mean that one of the tables is empty or that the where condition contains some condition that could never be satisfied, such as "where 1=0".

To isolate the problem, I created a copy of the database and removed everything but the tables and rows necessary to duplicate the problem.  To eliminate possible problems, I deleted all the indexes on one of the tables.

I even tried:

```
mysql> select * from A where id=23;
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 23 |
+----+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from B where A_id=23;
+------+------+
| A_id | B_id |
+------+------+
|   23 |   10 |
|   23 |   13 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So this join should yield at least one row.  Something has to be broken, but I can't figure out what.

See https://gist.github.com/3150634

Answer (score 2):

You have used wrong character in your where condtion. Replace ' with `:

```
SELECT  `A`.`id` 
FROM  `demo`.`A` AS  `A` 
INNER JOIN  `demo`.`B` AS  `B` 
ON (  `A`.`id` = `B`.`A_id` )
```

Answer (score 1):

Should this not be

```
ON (  `A`.`id` = `B`.`A_id` )
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Change 'B.A_id'  into

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  `A`.`id`  
FROM  `demo`.`A` AS  `A`  
INNER JOIN  `demo`.`B` AS  `B`  
ON (  `A`.`id` = `B`.`A_id' )
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was going on.  In the original query, CakePHP generated

```
... ON (  `Equipment`.`id` = 'ql.equipment_id' AND ...
```

So ql.equipment_id is given as a constant string.  No wonder MySQL tagged the condition as "impossible"!

I need to squint harder when I look at those!

Thanks to all for your quick responses.